Does the First Federation of the TOS episode The Corbomite Maneuver ever resurface in alpha canon?
In the TOS episode "The Corbomite Maneuver", the Enterprise encounters the First Federation vessel Fesarius and its lone occupant Balok. In TOS "The Deadly Years", we get a subtle callback by way of Kirk's re-cycling of his corbomite bluff. Given that the Federation has effectively made friends with a seemingly very powerful civilization, it ought to reappear in subsequent alpha canon but so far as I can tell, it does not. Does it turn up again, at least subtly, or is it entirely forgotten? I am looking for intentional references, not what a viewer might infer. For example, in TOS "Journey to Babel", there is a reception scene in which we see a couple of diminutive ambassadors(?) who might be inferred to be from the First Federation, but it is not stated as such in dialog. Are they in script or other production documents? What about other episodes, series or movies?

Only a comment, but according to Memory Alpha, which is usually quite complete, there's very limited (canon) info on the First Federation: https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/First_Federation

@HansOlo Curious that despite evidence of trade (the tranya in DS9, etc.), their apparently more powerful fleet never so much as gets a mention, let alone participate in any Federation conflicts.

I fully agree! I think the First Federation was intended to be the "new alien species of the week" in TOS.
On the other hand, it was also mentioned in the wiki that their species was in a decline by the time of TOS, so perhaps by the 24-25th centuries, their fleet was not so powerful any more to be worth a mention. Still, it's a good point, my +1.

As of the date of this answer (December 2024), I can find no evidence of the First Federation itself ever mentioned again in any broadcast episode or movie.
"Tranya", the drink offered to Kirk and company by Balok in TOS: The Corbomite Maneuver, makes a few appearances across various series, such as in DS9: Facets, Picard: Stardust City Rag, and Discovery: Will You Take My Hand (the scene in question features a now-much-older Clint Howard, who played Balok in TOS).
I cannot answer the question about whether the First Federation gets mentioned in script notes or production documents, as I know of no publicly-available source for such items.
(This answer relies upon the following sources: Memory Alpha, Ex Astris Scientia, The Star Trek Transcripts on Chakoteya, and, the classic method of watching the shows.)

Good answer, but... I swear that it was mentioned in Prodigy (?) - just in passing once. I'll see if I can dig it out.

I don't recall any such mention in dialogue anywhere. If it was an Easter egg in an on-screen graphic or something, I do not recall. But I really don't remember seeing anything about it in Prodigy. (Which I always forget to mention in my sources list, I guess because it's animated...)

Got it, sort of. It was "furthest" Federation outpost (S1 Ep 11 "Asylum"), but spoken casually - I'd picked it up wrongly.
